# Is the beta-binomial distribution a conjugate prior for some distribution?

Tags: bayesian, conjugate-prior, hypergeometric-distribution, beta-binomial-distribution

The beta distribution is conjugate prior for the binomial distribution.

Is the beta-binomial distribution a conjugate prior for some sampling distribution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the [hypergeometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Discrete_distributions) distribution. Incidentally, this link is one of the first two hits on Google for `"beta binomial" "conjugate prior"`.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Table_of_conjugate_distributions), there's a very nice conjugate prior table there.

If you are working with `python`, you can import the [conjugate_prior](https://github.com/urigoren/conjugate_prior) package and start hacking